# How to use a font unicode that is stored in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list of objects called SidebarItems, this list may change according to what Module the user is in. I have downloaded and got Font Awesome Pro working in my application, However I must use the Unacode to access the correct icon inside the font.

**The SidebarNavItem**

```cs
public record SidebarNavItem(string Title, string ViewName, string IconUnicode);
public class SidebarItems:IReadOnlyCollection<SidebarNavItem>
{
    //Left this out for brevity
}
```

**The Xaml That its being used**

```xml
<Button Style="{StaticResource LabeledIconButton}" 
        Content="{Binding IconUnicode}" Grid.Row="0" 
        behaviors:ButtonBehavior.Label="{Binding Title}"
        Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding ViewName}"/>
```

[image]

This is what I'm getting but when I type it into the button, I get this:

```xml
<Button Style="{StaticResource LabeledIconButton}" 
        Content="&#xf319;" Grid.Row="0" 
        behaviors:ButtonBehavior.Label="{Binding Title}"
        Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding ViewName}"/>
```

[image]

How can I store these codes in `SidebarItems`?

Comment: the icon is not interpreted as raw value but as a string, therfore the engine does not render it correctly, if you would have your icon as a static resource it should work when the font is loaded in the context, i think thats how i solved it for fontawesome in xamarin

Comment: can you please change the above code and reply with the anwser, as I am not sure on what you are saying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `&#x` with `\u` and remove the trailing `;` from the `string` value returned from the property.

So `&#xf319;` becomes:

```
public string IconUnicode => "\uf319";
```

Comment: That worked! thank you, can you please explain why that worked?

Comment: `\u` is the unicode escape sequence in C#. It's different in XAML.